0.5\textwidth + 0.5\textwidth is longer than \textwidth
Consider the following MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{\textwidth} }
        \toprule
        Column1 \\
        \midrule
        Entry 1 \\
        \bottomrule                    
    \end{tabular}%
    \caption{1 Column}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth} p{0.5\textwidth}}
        \toprule
        Column1 & Column2\\
        \midrule
        Entry 1 & Entry 2\\
        \bottomrule                    
    \end{tabular}%
    \caption{2 columns}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.2\textwidth} p{0.2\textwidth}}
        \toprule
        Column1 & Column2 & Column3 & Column4 & Column5\\
        \midrule
        Entry1 & Entry2 & Entry3 & Entry4 & Entry5\\
        \bottomrule                    
    \end{tabular}%
    \caption{2 columns}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}

Each time I add more columns (still adding up to a total of 1\textwidth) the further into the margin my table goes.
Essentially I am trying to make my many tables within my document fit in a style. A lot of people said I shouldn't use \resizebox to make things fit within text width, but to instead change the font size or the spacing. But I don't understand how these are different? If I change the box size and keep the aspect ratio, then isn't that just the same as changing the font size? Should all tables in the same document share the same font size?

There is space before, between and after the columns, you can see the difference if you remove the space: @{}p{0.5\textwidth}@{}p{0.5\textwidth}@{}

This is due to the \tabcolsep, have a look here to remove it.

"If I change the box size and keep the aspect ratio, then isn't that just the same as changing the font size?" No. Many fonts have differently shaped glyphs for different sizes to make them easily readable. Also you don't want to combine all kinds of random font sizes, but a set which is harmonic and works well together.

scaling and choosing a different font are different in two ways, firstly fonts may not just scale, 5pt computer modern roman is not half size 10pt computer modern roman, and secondly you should pick as suitable named size such as \small or \footnotesize do not just choose some arbitrary size so each table is inconsistent.  You would not (hopefully) justify paragraph text by choosing an artifically chosen fontsize for each paragrah so things fitted exactly, why do that for tabes?

Well because by definition each table has a completely arbitrary number of columns and rows depinding entirely on the data being displayed. Where is this rule that font sizes in a document must come from a discrete set of font sizes? From these comments you are suggesting that I either use normal size font (not possible, doesn't fit), small font (still doesn't fit) or footnote size? Those are my only 3 font size options in the whole document?

@lukygee There are more than 3 predefined sizes.

Sure, but smaller than main size specifically (which I would need since my table is too big not too small). I see \tiny, \scriptsize, \footnotesize, and \small as my options for a table too large?

@lukygee Some classes also have \Tiny. So plenty of options to come up with a table layout which fits on the page.

column tables have \tabcolsep padding on either side, that has a default of 6pt so each p column takes 12pt more than the specified length (which is the length for linebreaking within the column)
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.5\textwidth}@{} p{0.5\textwidth}@{}}

would fit but the text in the columns would touch.
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax} p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}{}}

removes the padding from the outer borders and accounts for the tabcolsep from the inner borders.

If the table has | vertical rules  this should be accounted for, where is the rule width stored? and how much space is allocated around it?

with standard tabular the rule takes no width, with array package it is \arrayrulewidth wide || also contributes \doublerulesep @yannisl

I would also add to this putting the whole table in a box {\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} \begin{tabular} ....    } works too

@lukygee you meanb a group not a box, the table environmrnt is already a group so having anb extra {...} doesn't do anything here.

There's a crucial difference between the usable and the total width of a column. LaTeX inserts vertical whitespace, in the amount of \tabcolsep, on either side of a column. This means that if the tabular environment contains n columns of type p{\textwidth/n}, the default total width of the tabular environment will be \textwidth + 2*n*\tabcolsep.
Many LaTeX document classes set 6pt as the default value of \tabcolsep.
